# Pausing a thread until manually resumed

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

How do I put a thread into paused/sleep state until I manually resume it in c# ?

Currently I am aborting the thread but this is not what I am looking for. The thread should sleep/pause until it something triggers it to wake up.

Comment: I've never done this before but I am thinking along the lines of blocking the thread using a ManualResetEvent.

Comment: @ByteBlast: It does look like a duplicate, however the answer on the other question isn't particularly great :/

Comment: Make sure to do this only to a background thread. A UI thread (any thread that has joined a COM STA, usually the main thread, and generally any thread that owns a window for any reason) *must* continue to run and pump messages or it will cause stability problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should do this via a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent();
mre.WaitOne();  // This will wait
```

On another thread, obviously you'll need a reference to the `ManualResetEvent` instance.

```
mre.Set(); // Tells the other thread to go again
```

A full example which will print some text, wait for another thread to do something and then resume:

```
class Program
{
    private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SleepAndSet));
        t.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
        mre.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Resuming");
    }

    public static void SleepAndSet()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        mre.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot it :)

Answer (score 4):

Look into [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) or [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).